# How to animate widget generated by StreamBuilder?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to generate content of my screen by using StreamBuilder. It's working pretty well along bloc pattern, but there is one thing that I'm struggling with. 
How to animate changes between generated content (WidgetA and WidgetB) like fade or slide effect?

```
    ...
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
      child: BlocBuilder<ContentEvent, int>(
        bloc: bloc,
        builder: (context, contentID) {
          if (contentID == 1) {
            return WidgetA();
          } else {
            return WidgetB();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
    ...
```

Comment: see `AnimatedSwitcher`

Comment: @pskink I've tried this approach, but when BlocBuilder is wrapped in AnimatedSwitcher it doesn't animate at all.

Comment: `AnimatedSwitcher` works just fine, post your code then

Comment: @pskink It's very likely that I'm using it wrong. :) I've updated the code in the post with my current AnimatedSwitcher solution.

Comment: try: `builder: (context, contentID) { return AnimatedSwitcher(...);}`

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lot, it works like a charm! :)

Comment: good, your welcome - btw it you want different transition use `transitionBuilder` parameter passed to `AnimatedSwitcher`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `BlocBuilder` should wrap the `AnimatedSwitcher` and not the opposite.

The animation of `AnimatedSwitcher` happens when its direct child change. But in your case, the direct child is *always* `BlocBuilder`.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
      child: snapshot.hasData
        ? Text(snapshot.data)
        : CircularProgressIndicator();
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for this quite long

Comment: Note that if the types are the same (say if you wrap the switcher's widgets in Container or Centre) then the animation won't happen unless you give them different keys. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

Answer (score 2):

You could try with AnimatedCrossFade
It accepts 2 children, duration and state (AnimatedCrossFadeState.showFirst and AnimatedCrossFadeState.showSecond) and it will animate fade between two children.

documentation: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html